# Pymongo Can't take a integer id which made by Node.JS

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a Mongo DB Collections which created by Node.JS
_id had been created by auto increment integer (not object ID of Pymongo)

I have no problem when query for another field in document like email, name (not key)
However I try to take a document when use _id like below query

```
user_id = 1234 // only integer
users = db.find_one({_id : user_id}
```

Python Return None result even though exist in document and collection absolutely.

I guess Pymongo can't support _id which composed by only integer.
Is it right ?

Would you like to advise me how to resolve it ..

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

user_id = str(1234)
user = db.find_one({"_id" : ObjectId(user_id)})
```

I found this in the docs:

> A common task in web applications is to get an ObjectId from the request URL and find the matching document. It’s necessary in this case to convert the ObjectId from a string before passing it to find_one

Please see the original [here](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html#querying-by-objectid)